# Installing drone on a sub-directory/path

Tags: drone.io, caddy

I am trying to install drone in a particular path of a domain, but it still tries to find it's resources in root directory. It's behind a Caddy Server.
Example:-
Want to install in 
`http://abc.xyz.com/drone/`

While it should find its resources(static,api,feed) likw
`http://abc.xyz.com/drone/static/app.css`
It tries to find it in
`http://abc.xyz.com/static/app.css`

I can write URL re-writes but it seems counter intuitive, and could be prone to errors.
How do I correct this?

My current caddyfile:-

```
https://abc.xyz.com { 
    proxy /drone/ http://127.0.0.1:8000 {
        transparent
        websocket
    }

}
```

Comment: Installing drone in a subpath is not supported. See https://github.com/drone/drone/issues/475